# iPhone 3.0 way of repositioning a table view with a textField + keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a tableView with cells that contain UITextField in them. Prior to 3.0, in order to get the tableView to readjust itself when a textField got focus, I'd have to set a new frame for the entire tableView and use CGRectOffset in order to get it to properly display. This is for tableViews that do not have enough scrollable content, such as two or three cells in the middle of a UIViewController.

Is there anyway to simplify this using iPhone 3.0? I would just like the tableView to reposition itself once the textField has focus so that the keyboard does not cover the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this without any extra code? I've found that in 3.0 and later, iPhone table views will automatically adjust a table view (which inherits from UIScrollView) to keep an editing UITextField visible above a keyboard. The only problem I ran into was when I started messing with the bounds of the keyboard itself - until then, I didn't have to do anything at all to make the keyboard work with the table view cells' text fields.

If it doesn't work out of the box for you, check out [this blog post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html) - it's incredibly helpful and detailed about how to move views around to keep a text field visible around the keyboard.